# Display Admob banner after closing Popup

Tags: javascript, android, admob

Here's what my program do :
when I click on a button it's opening a popup with a youtube video, I can close the popup by touching outside the window (I've created a customtheme in styles.xml and applied it)

Everything work, the ad, popup ... BUT Google send an email to tell me that I don't respect their policies, after some research I figured out that you're not allowed to use an Admob Banner while a Youtube video is playing ...

So I added a destroy and hide adview when I click on the button to show the popup, but I can't figure out how to show it again after clicking outside my popup window.

Here's my code :

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate : Starting.");
    View v = getView();

    BteyoutubePlay = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.BteyoutubePlay);
    mYoutubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) v.findViewById(R.id.youtubePlay);

    BteyoutubePlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Pop.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            mAdview.destroy();
            mAdview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });}
```

The pop.class is my popup window with the youtube video.
This is my custom theme in style.xml :

```
    <style name="AppTheme.CustomTheme">
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    </style>
```

and this is how I applied it in my manifest :

```
      <activity android:name=".Pop"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.CustomTheme"  >
      </activity>
```

I know that I have to use loadAd and setvisibility to show the ad again but I don't know where to put it :

```
    mAdview.loadAd(adRequest);
    mAdview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Thanks for your help !
Cordially,
LooK

Comment: in the onCreate method of the pop activity

Comment: Hello, thanks I'll try this !

Comment: I've made a getter that return the state of the ad, and used it in the pop activity : HomeFragment.get_mAdview().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

But it's hidding the ad and showing it again a second after while the video is playing (and the popup is open) ... I don't know how to show it again after I close my popup :(

Answer (score 0):

Here's a summary of my pop.java :

```
public class Pop extends YouTubeBaseActivity {
private static final String TAG = "Pop";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cassage);

    //------------------------PUB--------------------------------//
    HomeFragment.get_mAdview().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //OUVRE LA PUB
    //----------------------FIN PUB------------------------------//
   //---------------------------------------------------------//
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;
    getWindow().setLayout((int) (width*.77),(int)(height*.76));
    //---------------------------------------------------------//
 }
}
```

And here's my getter that I've created in my Fragment :

```
    public static AdView get_mAdview()
    {
    return (mAdview);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I woke up at 4 am to code again and found the solution, I don't know why I did not think about this before.

It was pretty easy, just added a protected void onStop() in the pop activity and in it added the admob banner to visible.

Thanks to Matio for the help ! :)